# Java - Get chosen option in JPanel without polling

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, future, completion-service

I've got a JPanel which instances another JPanel in a pretty similar way as `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)`. But I don't use this option because I want to change the size, message, buttons positions, and some more stuff. But the final utility must be the same, returning the selected option as soon as it's chosen. The thing is that I don't want to have to poll an attribute which may be initialized to null until it's changed from the `actionPerformed(...)` method. Instead, I had thought to use somehow a `CompletionService`, but I'm not able to think how to do it exactly. How shall I define it? Because I guess the `Future` has to be picked in a `getSelectedOption()` method, but it has to be generated in the  `actionPerformed(...)` one. How to do this?

Comment: Side comment: [SwingWorkers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) seem more appropriate in your case (they roughly do what a CompletionService does, but with better integration with the UI thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is the embed your panel in a JDialog which is modal `setModal(true)`.

This way you can have a static method which initialize your panel and whatever, invoke the `setVisible(true)` (blocking since the dialog is modal). Then once the user click the Ok button (which close the dialog), you can retrieve the selected option.

```
public static MyOption showMyDialog() {
    final JDialog myDialog = new JDialog();
    myDialog.add(myPanel);
    myDialog.setModal(true);
    myDialog.setVisible(true); // blocker since the dialog is modal

    return myPanel.getSelectedOption();
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the solution I was looking for, since I'm not stopping the main GUI thread, but logically the results are the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a subclass of JOptionPane and do the layout you want and still use the return method.